# Contar linhas Scanner

Tags: java

Será que alguém poderia me explicar como contar as linhas de um texto Scanner de maneira a que depois de as contar possa voltar à linha inicial?

Comment: para que você precisa da quantidade de linhas que o Scanner leu? talvez exista uma opção melhor do que você está planejando

Comment: basicamente o que eu queria era "saltar" para a ultima linha mas não consigo, já tentei isto :

Comment: while(ficheiro.hasNextLine()){
 ficheiro.next();}    mas não estou a conseguir

Comment: quer saltar uma quantidade pré-definida de linhas? por exemplo, ignorar as 10 primeiras linhas de um scanner?

Comment: aí está, o numero de linhas que quero saltar não está definido

Comment: qual então seria a condição para saber quantas linhas deve pular?

Comment: só mesmo o numero de linhas total ... o problema é que eu ao contar o numero de linhas depois não consigo voltar para as linhas acima

Comment: obrigada pela ajuda

Comment: se a resposta resolveu seu problema por favor marque como aceita, clicando no V do abaixo da pontuação

Answer (score 4):

Você pode transferir todo o conteúdo do Scanner para um ArrayList, assim terá facilmente a quantidade de linhas que seu Scanner possuia, em seguida, você pode acessar ou percorrer seu ArrayList atrás do dado que lhe interessa. Exemplo:

```
List<String> textos = new ArrayList<>();
//le linha por linha enquanto alimenta seu ArrayList
while(sc.hasNext()) {
    textos.add(sc.next());
}
//mostra quantas linhas o Scanner leu
System.out.println("Seu scanner possuia " + textos.size() + " linhas"); 
//mostra o conteúdo da primeira linha
System.out.println("A primeira linha contém: " + textos.get(0));
sc.close();
```